# Adding Space between Columns using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to add a small gap in between two columns that I have created using Bootstrap Grid, with little success.  I have tried a few different things:

- I have tried setting a container width, because at the moment it doesn't have one, and is just set to default.
- Adding a class below the row class (this seems a common theme amongst other feeds that I have explored)
- Changing the size of the columns that I am creating.

All of the above has come to nothing, unfortunately. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 style= "color: red;"> News </h1>
        <p style= "color: red;"> HEADLINES FROM AROUND THE WORLD </p>
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3> Headlines </h3>
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#World"> World </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Politics"> Politics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Technology">Technology</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Science">Science</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#Entertainment">Entertainment</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class = "tab_structure">
                    <div class = "tab" id = "World">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <p>World</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab" id = "Politics">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <p>Politics</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab" id = "Technology">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <p>Tech</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab" id = "Science">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <p>Sci/p>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "tab" id = "Entertainment">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <p>Entertainment/p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h3> Most Popular </h3>
                Hello World
                <br>
                <br> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.container {

    width: 1200px;
}


**.col-md-6 {

    background-color: pink;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.col-md-6 {

    background-color: pink;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}**
```

Comment: So what you want is a space between Headlines and most popular right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @JoelBanks

Comment: You're better off customising the template to change the gutter widths. There's more to it than just adding more space due to the way Bootstrap sets up the margins. Alternatively just wrap your content in a div and add margins to that.

Comment: That's the issue I'm having. Can you give me some guidance as to how to set the gutter widths?

Comment: You need to use this tool https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ and edit the `@grid-gutter-width` value

Comment: Presumably I use @grid-gutter-width? Where do I implement this in the code? CSS or HTML?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of that page, press "compile and download" and use the new CSS instead of the normal Bootstrap css.